# How to wait for a certain condition to met and hide/show an UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't find a way to check for 3 [or more] conditions to met in order to show or hide an `UIButton` in a view. I need to show an `UIButton` only when the user has filled all the UITextField in a view. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: We need more information, what do you mean by "wait"? is the button hidden by default or it goes hidden after certain condition? what type of conditions are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `UITextFields delegates`. You can for instance trigger some code as soon as the user has finished editing a `textfield`, for example you can check that the length of each `myTextfield.text is > 0`, i.e. the field was filled with some text. Whenever the above condition is satisfied for **all** your `textfields` you can hide/show your `UIButton`.

Maybe post some code you tried but if you look at how `UITextFields delegates` work you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textfield delegate methods: 
Use `"textfieldDidBeginEditing"` method..

Confirm this delegate for your 3rd textfield

In this method, check if 1st 2 textfield are filled, If "YES" then show the button.

For this 3rd textfield, in `"textFieldDidEndEditing"` .. keep a check if user has filled this 3rd textfield  .. if "NOT" then hide the button.

Post some code.. so that we could get more idea for what you are doing.

Comment: This solution is not correct because if the user fill the textfields in this order: 2 - 3 - 1 (other bad combinations are available) the conditions will never be satisfied. You should check for each textfield edited the condition on all existing textfields.

Comment: @playitgreen: Yes .. you are right.
Actually ..I was just helping with the logic .. combinations and things was expected to be handled on his own.